# Can you perform GetIntent requests with KnowledgeBase results through Java Client API?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I am investigating how to include knowledge-base responses in my application which makes heavy use of Dialogflow to do back end processing of intents. I know to use this capability, one has to include the "names" of the knowledge bases they wish to search with the Query object (otherwise Dialogflow will not bother searching) but I'm having trouble initialisng that query object.

I've managed to look through the (poor) Google documentation on this feature and have come across [this code sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/dialogflow/cloud-client/src/main/java/com/example/dialogflow/DetectIntentKnowledge.java) but looking through the JavaDoc it looks like some of the methods referenced aren't yet implemented.

Per [this page of documentation](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-clients/latest/index.html?com/google/cloud/dialogflow/v2/package-summary.html) it would appear that the method is not yet implemented.

Just to be clear, the offending line is:

```
        QueryParamaters params = QueryParameters.newBuilder().addKnowledgeBaseNames(kbName).build();
```

With KB name being a string. Perhaps it needs to be of a KnowledgeBaseName type, which is mentioned in the docs but, I've no information on how to actually... initialise such an object... so... *shrug*

Even trying it in the wild I get the following error:

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    QueryParamaters cannot be resolved to a type
    The method addKnowledgeBaseNames(String) is undefined for the type QueryParameters.Builder
```

Perhaps I'm just supplying the wrong argument but it looks like more is missing than just that. I'm not even really able to resolve QueryParameters. Perhaps this is all in a later version than I am working with (google-cloud-dialogflow-0.77.0-alpha.jar) in which case some guidance on what to upgrade to for the jar file would be much appreciated.